# Why does no animation occur when clicking view?

Tags: android, android-animation

I'm using this code:

```
package com.example.tileanimator;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.animation.Animation;
import android.view.animation.AnimationUtils;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.GridView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        GridView gridview = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridview);
        final ImageAdapter ia = new ImageAdapter(this);
        gridview.setAdapter( ia );

        gridview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,
                                    int position, long id) {

                        for( int i = 0; i < ia.getCount(); i++ ) {
                            if( position != i ) {
                                View toFade = ia.getView(i, null, parent);
                                fadeout( toFade );
                                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Fading out: " + i,
                                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                        }
            }
        });
    }

    private void fadeout( View v ) {;

        v.setAlpha(1f);
        v.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        v.animate()
                .alpha(0f)
                .setDuration(1000);

    }
}
```

Basically, the example found here: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/gridview.html

When I click on any of the images, I see the Toast, but no animation is displayed. Any idea why?

(I'm also confused whether passing null as the second parameter to getView() is a bad idea, and if so, what to pass instead.)

If it matters, my ImageAdapter is here:

```
package com.example.tileanimator;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.GridView;
import android.widget.ImageView;

/**
 * Created by xrdawson on 11/17/16.
 */

public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Context mContext;

    public ImageAdapter(Context c) {
        mContext = c;
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return mThumbIds.length;
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return null;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    // create a new ImageView for each item referenced by the Adapter
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ImageView imageView;
        if (convertView == null) {
            // if it's not recycled, initialize some attributes
            imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
            imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
            imageView.setPadding(8, 8, 8, 8);
        } else {
            imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
        }

        imageView.setImageResource(mThumbIds[position]);
        return imageView;
    }

    // references to our images
    private Integer[] mThumbIds = {
            R.drawable.sample_2, R.drawable.sample_3,
            R.drawable.sample_4, R.drawable.sample_5,
            R.drawable.sample_6, R.drawable.sample_7,
            R.drawable.sample_0, R.drawable.sample_1,
            R.drawable.sample_2, R.drawable.sample_3,
            R.drawable.sample_4, R.drawable.sample_5,
            R.drawable.sample_6, R.drawable.sample_7,
            R.drawable.sample_0, R.drawable.sample_1,
            R.drawable.sample_2, R.drawable.sample_3,
            R.drawable.sample_4, R.drawable.sample_5,
            R.drawable.sample_6, R.drawable.sample_7
    };
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I was not actually retrieving a view inside the application. By calling `View toFade = ia.getView(i, null, parent);` with null as the second parameter, I was generating a new view that was not attached to the view hierarchy. The correct code to get the view for animating should be something like this:

```
View toFade = gridview.getChildAt( i );

if( toFade != null && v != toFade ) {
  fadeout( toFade, i );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

- First move your toast inside your fade method. To confirm the method Fade is functional.
- Second, I noticed an unnecessary semicolon right after the first brace of your fadeout method. Remove it

  p....( View v ) {;  <----------
- third, you're applying the alpha's on the v twice?

  ```
  v.setAlpha(1f);
  v.animate()
          .alpha(0f)
  ```

remove the initial one. One should suffice.

- fourth nullify the clicklistener right after .setDuration, likewise :

  ```
  private void fadeout( View v ) {;
    v.setAlpha(1f);
    v.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    v.animate()
          .alpha(0f)
          .setDuration(1000)
          .setListener(null);
  ```
- Lastly, if all the previous helps not, then carry on by bringing the grid view to the fadeout method and also use a switch statement

  ```
  private void fadeout( View v ) {

    switch(v.getId()){


       case R.id.gridview:




  gridview.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
  gridview.animate()
          .alpha(0f)
          .setDuration(1000)
          .setListener(null);



    break;

   }
  ```

Answer (score -1):

Try to use

```
fade(v)
```

code instead, see if it works.

Comment: Where does that function come from? Do you mean to say, rename it?